# Distributing students across classes based on marks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

| Name | Marks | Rank | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Eddie | 20 | 6 | C |
| Tom | 10 | 10 | A |
| Jenny | 30 | 4 | A |
| Riva | 40 | 3 | C |
| Andy | 50 | 2 | B |
| Mark | 5 | 11 | B |
| Sally | 78 | 1 | A |
| Jack | 15 | 8 | B |
| Dick | 15 | 8 | C |
| Harry | 20 | 6 | A |
| Dom | 30 | 4 | B |

The students are expected to be distributed across classes A, B and C, based on their marks in the above picture.
The student with the highest marks goes in A. The one with the next highest goes in B. The next highest goes in C. The next goes again to A and so on.
What should be the formula to be used in Excel 2013 and above for calculating the Class?

Comment: Excel 2013 and above? So you have acces to Microsoft365? Also, you should add the data as markdown sample data instead of a picture. Include your attempt at a formula too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Excel 365, you can use the **SORTBY** function to solve the question.

Assume the `Name` column is in a named range called **List_Name**, the `Marks` column is in a named range called **List_Marks**, your example dataset is in range `A1:D12`, and you want to return the class code in column D.

In cell `D2`, enter any one of the following formulas and drag it down:

```
=CHOOSE(MOD(MATCH(A2,SORTBY(List_Name,List_Marks,-1),0),3)+1,"C","A","B")
```

Alternatively, you can use the following in cell `D2` instead:

```
=INDEX({"C";"A";"B"},MOD(MATCH(A2,SORTBY(List_Name,List_Marks,-1),0),3)+1)
```

[image: Solutions]

If you cannot use the **SORTBY** function, then the answer provided by Ron Rosenfeld should do the job quite well.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

- Sort the table by either `Marks` **descending** or `Rank` **ascending**.
- `D2: =CHOOSE(MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,3)+1,"A","B","C")`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the chart you provided is in cells A1-D11

Try making a 2x3 chart on the side (I’m using F2-G4 with 1...A 2...B 0...C

and then put the formula in D1 as follows: =vlookup(mod(C2,3),F2:G4, false)

You could even skip out the whole C column if you wanted, writing =vlookup(mod(rank(A2,B:B),3),F2:G4, false)

But then you might have an issue of 2 people going to the same class if they rank the same.